# How to display multiple controls in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have list all the words from database and put them into UITableViewCell.

The next step is I have to display many controls in the UITableViewCell. I don't know how to display flexible label width and then sound and also other controls.

Can anyone help me what I should use to have many controls inside UITableViewCell look like the red line in picture below!!

[image]

Thank

Comment: you have to used the custom cell for that..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own UITableViewCell subclassing it, they defaults one doesn't provide you that.

Find all the info in this guide:

[UITableViewProgramming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)